MotionLayout Views Move Out of Parent Bounds When ConstraintSets Differ
I’m working with MotionLayout to implement animations,
but I’ve encountered an unexpected issue and could use some guidance.
Problem
I have a MotionScene with start and end ConstraintSets to define an animation. When the start and end ConstraintSets have identical constraints, all views stay properly within the parent layout boundaries. However, when the constraints in start and end differ, two views, tv_detail_result_title_sub1 and btn_detail_result_title_info1, move out of the parent layout bounds during or after the transition.
Xml Layout
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1px"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1px"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Last"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_search_24" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" + "
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_search_24" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_detail_result_this"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_total_title_this"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_voice_this"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_detail_total_title_this"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tv_detail_total_title_this"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="0 min"
                android:minWidth="40dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_sms_this"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_this"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_this"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="0 count"
                android:minWidth="40dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_lte_this"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_detail_result_sms_this"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_detail_result_sms_this"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="0 MB"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_total_this"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:hint="0$"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_detail_result_total_this"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_detail_result_total_this"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#d7d7d7" />
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:id="@+id/ml_detail_result_keep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_detail_result_detail_keep"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/sbg_button_rect"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnFoldAction"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnFoldAction"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/sbg_button_rect"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_title_keep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="0 min"
                android:minWidth="40dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_detail_result_title_keep"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_detail_result_title_keep"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_sms_keep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="0 count"
                android:minWidth="40dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_lte_keep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="0 MB"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_detail_result_sms_keep"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_sms_keep"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_info_keep"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="60dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
    
            <include
                android:id="@+id/detail_mobile_result_price"
                layout="@layout/include_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_title_sub1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_info_keep"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_title_sub1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail_mobile_result_price" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_detail_result_title_info1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_detail_result_title_sub1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_detail_result_title_sub1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_title_sub1"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

Include Layout
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_vat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VAT"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_mandatory_total"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />
    
    
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_mandatory_total_summary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="1Price"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="21dp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="1dp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_mandatory_total"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_mandatory_total"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_mandatory_total"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_mandatory_total"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_mandatory_total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="0$"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="38dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_exemption_total"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_exemption_total_summary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="2Price"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_exemption_total"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_detail_result_exemption_total"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_detail_result_exemption_total"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_exemption_total"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_exemption_total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="0$"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_detail_result_message"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:hint="TEXT"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="21dp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="5dp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Motion Scene
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MotionScene
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <Transition
            motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
            motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
            motion:duration="500">
           <KeyFrameSet>
           </KeyFrameSet>
            <OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/btnFoldAction" />
        </Transition>
    
        <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
            <Constraint
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_info_keep"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep"
                motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />
        </ConstraintSet>
    
        <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
            <Constraint
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_result_info_keep"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_detail_result_voice_keep"
                motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />
        </ConstraintSet>
    </MotionScene>

Question
Why does changing the ConstraintSet cause views to move out of the parent bounds?
What’s the best way to prevent this behavior?
